# mod rewrite not working after dist-upgrade debian 7 to 8

Tags: debian, mod-rewrite

I needed to upgrade my Debian OS version on a server, from 7 to 8.
So i did :

- `aptitude update`
- `aptitude upgrade`
  to have the latest wheezy packages, then
- change in /etc/apt/source.list (and other source.list.d/ files) the term wheezy to jessie
- `aptitude update`
- `aptitude dist-upgrade`
- i rebooted the server

Then i changed my vhost file names with the new config extension :

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain to /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.conf

here's one example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/web
        <Directory /var/www/mydomain/web>
            Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-mydomain.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-mydomain.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and after that i restarted apache service

In that case, the website was reachable, BUT, it wasn't working properly because the rewrite rules didn't apply !

Though,

- I checked the apache config had no error
- the mod_rewrite module was active (it was in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ and in phpinfo())
- i also tried to remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` statement in the vhost, leaving the rewrite rules and reloading the config : the rules weren't followed.
- i also tried to put the rewrite rules in a .htaccess at the root of the website : it didn't work as well

This is most disturbing.

What could be the problem ?
what log or config file should i check ?
Are there other step i should do when upgrading Debian 7 to 8 concerning the rewrite module ?

Thank you

Comment: Typically you check the the error log, either the virtual host specific one you defined  (error-mydomain.log) or the generic apache error log.

Comment: i forgot to mention i did. And there was no message concerning the rewrite...

Comment: Next time, *especially* for such invasive changes as upgrading the entire operating system, I recommend doing it in staging before doing it to production.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but I found the answer.

Go to:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

and edit your file of vhosts (my file was called 000-default.conf)

And you must add this

> AllowOverride All

or

> AllowOverride FileInfo

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory />
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ServerName tududu.pl
DocumentRoot /var/tududu
</VirtualHost>
```

after that you must

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: As you can see in my vhost, i already have this Allowoverride.

Comment: Add my code after your VirtualHost... and you will see, its works!

Comment: Note - AllowOverride ALL needs to be in a Directory container....